# Caching variables in PHP

Tags: php, caching, optimization

Long story short, I am looking for the best way to quickly and efficently store, mostly, boolean variables, like:

- Has current user viewed this page? (Boolean)
- Has current user voted for this page? (Boolean again)
- How many times today this user got points for voting? (Integer)

These variables are going to be stored only for ONE day, that is at midnight each day they will be removed.

I can think of five ways to accomplish this, but I don't know how to properly speedtest them, so I could certainly use some help with this.

### 1. Single File - Single Variable

The first idea is to store some variable in a file like this `<?php $___XYZ = true;`, then include it and return `$___XYZ`. The problem is, most likely there are going to be hundreds of these variables and this can take potentially a lot of space (since, correct me if I am wrong, each file takes minimum ~4KB of space, depending on partition format). Big plus is ease of access, easy to work with, and easy to clear the whole thing at the beginning of a day (just delete the whole folder with contents). Any problems with speed of access?

### 2. Single File - Many Variables

I could store groups of variables in one file, in such fashion:

```
0:1
1:1
14:0
154:0
```

Then use fgets to find and read the variable but what about writing mid-file? Can fwrite be used effectively? I am not really confident this way is much better than 1., but what do you think?

### 3. APC

Use apc_store and others to store, modify and access the data. I have three concerns here - I read somewhere that enabling APC can seriously slow down your site, that there are sometimes strange problems with caching, and am curious about how to effectively remove only the "daily" cache, and leave anything else I might have cached? And how fine is it with hundreds of thousands variables stored in it?

### 4. MySQL Database

I could create a table with two rows (name and variable) but... I have this feeling it will be painfully slow when compared to any from the above options.

---

To sum it up - which of these ways to store variables in PHP is the best? Or maybe there is something even better?

Comment: You don't need such caching at all. just use your regular database.

Comment: Take a look at point #4 in my post. Of course I can store it in database but from my point of view it isn't the best solution and I'd actually like to avoid it. I can make separate table for each group of data but that's useless cluttering for me, especially that the data is going to be pruned each night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For profiling, you can use [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler), which stores profiling informations in the defined folder, and use [webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/) to view the profiling data.

My settings in php.ini for xdebug:

```
zend_extension=C:/WEB/PHP-ts/php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc6.dll
xdebug.collect_params=4
xdebug.show_local_vars=on
xdebug.scream=1
xdebug.collect_vars=on
xdebug.dump_globals=on
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=C:/WEB/_profiler/
xdebug.profiler_output_name=cachegrind.%s.out
xdebug.collect_return=1
xdebug.collect_assignments=1
xdebug.show_mem_delta=1
```

And I found a [blog post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/09/cache-performance-comparison/) about cache performance comparison (but it's from 2006!):

```
Cache Type                Cache Gets/sec

Array Cache                       365000
APC Cache                          98000
File Cache                         27000
Memcached Cache (TCP/IP)           12200
MySQL Query Cache (TCP/IP)          9900
MySQL Query Cache (Unix Socket)    13500
Selecting from table (TCP/IP)       5100
Selecting from table (Unix Socket)  7400
```

Comment: I had real problems with setting up Xdebug (it worked from time to time), but I think setting the debugger is the little problem - I have no idea how to make test cases meaningful actually. Though these results are very interesting! I am only wondering if APC won't have problem with real lots of data?

Comment: I am using PHP5.3.3 Thread safe VC6 on Windows+Apache2.2, and using `php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc6.dll`. It's definitely worth to set it up correctly. Editing my answer to show all of my xdebug related settings from `php.ini`.

Answer (score 2):

What about memcached? It's really fast, and when you're just storing bools it all fits in memory no problem. It is definitely the fastest option of them all. At midnight, you can easily read out all the stats gathered during the day and clear the cache.

Comment: I was always somehow kind of scared of memcache (seeing how it requires going through some connection) and as other people mentioned APC seems to be faster. I won't be going for memcache unless I need to redistribute the site on more than one server which I hope won't happen too soon :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [memcached](http://memcached.org/), you can store variables in memory and set their expiry time, so they can be rotated like everyday.

Memcached is way faster than any other method you listed, if you're new to it, try [this class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6631-PHP-Manipulate-cached-entries-in-memcached-servers.html) i did.

Comment: Actually, it's slower than 3/4 of the methods listed.  It has network overhead associated with it (latency exists, even on localhost).  I'm not saying it's a bad idea (I think it's great and tied for the best solution for this problem along with `APC`), just don't be under the illusion that it's faster than local memory (`APC`) or local filesystem (on most servers).

Comment: especially seldom make use of parallel fetching

Comment: Do multi-get in single call, http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#Batch_your_requests_with_get_multi **OR** `array Memcache::get ( array $keys [, array &$flags ] )` use array http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.get.php

Comment: @ircmaxell is it from your own experience? what particular server you are talking about? how many files (if any) usually in use? thanks.

Comment: @Col: That was from a series of benchmarks I did about 1.5 years ago.  I ran it on 4 IBM servers (2 x Xeon, 2x SCSI RAID 1) across varying platforms and filesystems (including ext3, ext4, NTFS, and a few others).  It wasn't much slower mind you, in the micro-second range.  But it was slower...  And there were lots of files in use.  I'm not trying to say it's always slower or faster, just that *it's way faster than any other method* is blatantly false.

Comment: @ircmaxell well you have no real life experience. nuff said.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way of doing this is a variation of #2, where I make an array out of the number pairs.  Then it is easy to serialize the array and save it to a file.

For your application this has a disadvantage if multiple visitors/processes need access to the array at the same time.  Perhaps there is a way around that by using a separate file for each user.

Comment: Awesome idea with having separate files for each users, I haven't thought of that!

Comment: I am using [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php), and writing the output to the file (with some additional php code). This way there is no need for serialization, and I can just include the file.

Answer (score 1):

I would opt for mySQL and/or an in memory cache like APC or memcache.

Honestly, a properly indexed database table will probably be plenty fast for most operations. And you can easily clear all the records via a `DELETE` statement comparing timestamps.
It will definitely be faster than home-brew solution on the filesystem. And assuming you're already using mySQL for the rest of your site, you don't need to worry about an extra storage layer.

**EDIT:** I'd also like to point out that memory is volatile. Should your server lose power, your data will disappear if it's not persisted somewhere (like a database).

Comment: Well by taking a look at the speed comparison posted by *styu* it certainly has the problem of being much slower than, let's say, APC. Plus I have always had this feeling, that databases should be accessed as few times as possible, though I might possibly be wrong.

Comment: Sure, it's fast, but do you really need that speed? My attitude is: if you don't know that you need an in-memory caching layer, you don't need it. I'd be more interesting in hearing details about why you would consider mySQL a bottleneck in this situation, and under what sort of load you expect your site to be. That would better inform people providing answers.

Comment: I didn't say it would be a bottleneck. I am kind of repelled when usage of databases is in sight, that might be the problem. Plus, implementing the whole thing in, let's say, APC will be 20 times faster than in mySQL (for me at least). As for the load - it won't be a problem too soon, I guess it might be just another premature optimization on my side... And thirst for some knowledge too :)

Comment: A memory cache isn't really used to replace a database (it's not permanent storage mechanism). Mostly it's used to augment a db when the db becomes a bottleneck. Chances are, in the long run, you might want this data to hang around longer than 24 hours (also see my above note about server crashes). My suggestion is to put the data in a db first, and then add a caching layer if you want.

Comment: Well I already store any data which won't be pruned and is important in database. Lose of power is very valid argument here, but power loses don't happen every day, not even as often as once a month, and the data I am going to cache isn't that important to be stored (at worst some people would just get more points said day, nothing more, like timeshift). But You made me notice APC is Memory cache (I thought it was file based) which adds the problem of excessive use of RAM.